# Question about 意のままに

Tags: grammar

I can't understand quite the meaning of 意のままに in this sentence:

> おさえつけて自分の意のままにすること。

I got it from reading the definition of the word 制御. Does anybody know what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

意のまま has [an independent entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BE%E3%81%BE/#jn-9077) in a dictionary. It means 思うとおり *as one wishes*. So the whole phrase literally means *suppress and put sth at one's own mercy*.